# PhoneGap: InAppBrowser

Tags: android, html, cordova

I have installed the plugin:
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
I have followed their installation directions:

```
Installation

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser
If you want all page loads in your app to go through the InAppBrowser, 
you can simply hook window.open during initialization. For example:

document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
}
```

I have added this to my config.xml:

```
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" version="1.0.1" />
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
<param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
</feature>
```

This is my code to use the above:

```
    <a href="javascript:testOne();">Test 1</a>
    <br>
    <a href="javascript:testTwo();">Test 2</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
function testOne() {
    var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://google.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');
}
function testTwo() {
    var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://google.com', '_system', 'location=yes');
}
</script>
```

To no avail, when I click these links (on Android), nothing happens. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

`window.open(‘http://example.com’, ‘_blank’);`

without the document ready listener you have added.

Comment: Yes. I have tried window.open(‘http://example.com’, ‘_blank’); with the plugin added and without.